# Get classtype of class where method is called in async method

Tags: c#

I use a custom `LogManager` class to manage all my logs from my application. I have a function stated below that could find the class where the method was called from, so that I could easily detect where the log was coming from.

However after recently implementing some `async` methods in my application, I've ran into the problem that I seem to be unable to find the calling class from any `async` method using this function. (I seem to only be able to get the calling method)

I also tried including an object in parameters for the logging with a reference to `this`, and then getting the type of the object passed that way, however I have quite some static methods and this doesn't work for them. Also I'd rather not have to do this for every time I want to log something..

Does anybody have a better solution for finding where the class is called from for async methods?

---

My current function to find the calling location:

```
    private string GetLocation()
    {
        string location = "Unknown";
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(i);
            string foundLocation = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;

            if (!foundLocation.Contains("Log"))
            {
                location = foundLocation;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Detects if log is comming from async method, detects method instead of classtype however
        if (location.StartsWith("<"))
        {
            string[] temp = location.Split('>');
            location = temp[0].Replace("<", "");
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Current Log method:

```
    #region Log Method

    public static async void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string message, [CallerMemberName]string location = "")
    {
        LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage(logLevel, message, location);
        await AddLogToCollection(logMessage);
    }

    #region Aditional log methods

    // Log With Formating -> doesn't work, cannot add the CallerMemberName after a range of params..
    public static void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string message, params object[] args, [CallerMemberName]string location = "")
    {
        string formatString = String.Format(message, args);
        Log(logLevel, formatString, location);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
```

Comment: Could you use caller info attributes instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet I never knew about this, currently testing this out I'll come back if I have any results!

Comment: @JonSkeet I was trying to implement this, but I have a log method that takes arguments for string formating so I don't know where to add this parameter. Code added above!

Comment: @JonSkeet after some searching I was able to adjust my code and now it works perfectly! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by JonSkeet, a few changes to the way I was handeling my logs and the information I found in [this article](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/using-caller-info-attributes-in-c-50-to.html), I was able to solve my problem!

Since my `Log` method that supported formating had an overload of object arguments, I was unable to pass the `CallerMemberName` / `CallerFilePath` that way. I solved this by making the `Log` method require the `LogMessage` to be passed directly (and handle formating there), and the method and class added in that method.

Many thanks to JonSkeet for pointing me in the right direction!

---

Log method:

```
    public static async void Log(LogMessage logMessage, [CallerMemberName]string method = "", [CallerFilePath]string path = "")
    {
        logMessage.SetCaller(method, path);
        await AddLogToCollection(logMessage);
    }
```

SetCaller method:

```
    public void SetCaller(string method, string path)
    {
        string location = path;

        if (location.Contains("\\"))
        {
            string[] temp = location.Split('\\');
            location = temp[temp.Length - 1].Replace(".cs", "");
        }

        Method = method;
        Location = location;
    }
```